# How to click a button of android program through monkeyrunner?

Tags: android, jython, monkeyrunner

I succeeded to install apk file on android emulator using Jython (monkeyrunner.bat). I also used this line of code to start the main activity: device.startActivity(component=runComponent) Now what i want is to press a button on the activity which i launched, if the button name is "Submit" than how can i send key events to press this button. Thanks and please give response ASAP.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Up and down key events to go to a particular button and use center button to click on that button.

For example

```
device.press("DPAD_DOWN", MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP) or device.press("DPAD_UP", MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

to reach the particular button and then click that button using

```
device.press("DPAD_CENTER", MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

You can't click the button with the button name or id.

Answer (score 3):

Another method to click on the button is to use the touch event of the MonkeyDevice. With this method you can specify the location of the button and then send a touch event to the display. For example lets say your button locates at bottom center of the screen. then you can send a touch event like this

device.touch(240, 450, 'DOWN_AND_UP') - (For HVGA screen)

This will click the location (240, 450). These co-ordinates are calculated from left top corner and the first value is X co-ordinate.